# Package 'MyPackage 1.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, warning on custom nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget

I have my own nuget private server. I have a .NET Core console app and when referencing a nuget package that I created using dlls that were built in .NET Core 3.1
I get the following warning in VS2019

```
Package 'MyPackage 1.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

When I reference the dlls directly in the project I don't see this warning

My nuspec file is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <authors>pantonis</authors>
    <owners>pantonis</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">Proprietary</license>
    <projectUrl>https://www.example.com</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>https://www.example.com</iconUrl>
    <description>Helper Library</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="MyPackage.Contracts.dll" target="lib/netcoreapp3.1" />
    <file src="MyPackage.Contracts.pdb" target="lib/netcoreapp3.1" />
    <file src="MyPackage.dll" target="lib/netcoreapp3.1" />
    <file src="MyPackage.pdb" target="lib/netcoreapp3.1" />
  </files>
</package>
```

I am building using `nuget pack .\MyPackage.nuspec` and add the nupkg in the nuget server

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your package is created for `netcoreapp3.1`, but you are targeting NETFramework 4.6.1, the warning is pretty straightforward

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski target?

Comment: Anyone can help please?

Comment: @pantonis: Within your project's .csproj file, is there a TargetFramework attribute ? If so, can you paste the value here ?

Comment: @MihaiAlbert this is the target framework ```<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>```

Comment: @pantonis: So your project is targeting multiple frameworks. If you change the property to `netstandard2.0`, this should allow both frameworks you're using (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard#versions), and also make the warning go away. Can you give it a go ?